# How to df to a conditional string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, python-re

I am new to pandas, I am facing issue with adding df to a string. so I have a conditional string statement like this `"'bikes'>20"`, where bikes are the column name in a data frame. Now I want to add df before 'bikes', How do I do it? I have used this code below but it is not working
my code:

```
x="'bikes'> 20"
x = re.sub(r"([> =!<]==)", r'df[\1]', x)
```

this gives: `'bikes'> 20` but not adding the df

Want I want is: `df['bikes']>20`

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace it like you need, it not working, because `"df['bikes']>20"` is still string, not column compared by scalar like `df['bikes']>20`.

Here is possible use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bikes':[20,39,44]})

x="'bikes'> 20"

df = df.query(x.replace("'",''))
print (df)
   bikes
1     39
2     44
```

Working like:

```
df = df.query("bikes > 20")
print (df)
   bikes
1     39
2     44
```

EDIT: Solution with [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html):

```
x="'bikes'> 20"

print (pd.eval("df." + x.replace("'",'')))
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Working like:

```
print (pd.eval("df.bikes> 20"))
```

For me not working:

```
print (pd.eval('df["bikes"]>20'))
```

> ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize

Comment: though it is correct. I am looking for something else. So when I add df['bikes']>20. It usually gives the true, false results I am looking for that.

Comment: @krish - I know what mean, but it not working if replace `df[]` here, because still string.

Comment: @jezreael-But I thought I could use eval to evaluate that string.

Comment: @krish like `(df.eval("df['bikes']>20"))` with error `UndefinedVariableError: name 'df' is not defined`?

Comment: no,no. So, when I add df to bikes. that is this x="df['bikes']>20" and then I can evaluate this with eval(x) which gives me the excepted output. But I don't know how to add the df to the bikes

Comment: @krish - It is possible with `.` instead `[]`, added to answer.